# initialize squid

Tags: squid

I am getting this message when setting up squid for the first time, on mac os x using webmin.

```
Your Squid cache directory /usr/local/squid/var/cache has not been initialized.This must be done before Squid can be run.
```

When i click on the initialize cache button, i get the message

```
Initializing the Squid cache with the command /usr/local/squid/sbin/squid -f /usr/local/squid/etc/squid.conf -z ..
```

2011/09/15 10:05:44| Creating Swap Directories

when i go back to start squid it takes me to the first message it hasnt initialized the cache, what could be the problem?

Comment: is squid running under a different user? check the permissions on /usr/local/squid and the logs (cant tell you where they would be, check the config file for clues or look in /var/log/

Comment: I am running it as the root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, This is permission issue. 
What are the permissions on */usr/local/squid/* ? Who owns that directory?  You can change it:

To change owners:

*chown squid /usr/local/squid/*

Permissions:

*chmod u+rw /usr/local/squid*

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions on /usr/local/squid/ are set to the user squid runs under (even when started from root squid uses another user unless you call the squid binary directly (highly doubt it))

run something like this

```
chown -R squid /usr/local/squid/
```

where squid is the user squid is running under as set by the init.d script (or rc.d or whatever) then try starting it again.

if you cannot find the user you are running under check the squid.conf

Comment: Did you mean `chown` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

As i know

$squid -z

prepare all needed directories and files.

Comment: that just hangs on macOS for me :(.